# Given the premises p→q and ¬p→¬q, prove that p is logically equivalent to q

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

Given the premises p→q and ¬p→¬q, prove that p is logically equivalent to q.

I understand why this works, but I do not know how to construct a complete formal proof. 
So far, I have this:

premises:
p→q 
¬p→¬q

(p→q) ∧ (¬p→¬q) ⇔ T

apply contrapositive law
(p→q) ∧ (q→p) ⇔ T
∴ (p↔q) ⇔ T

At this point, how do I formally assert (using symbols and laws) that, because (p↔q) is a tautology, p and q must be logically equivalent to each other?

Comment: If $p$ is true, $q$ must also be true , otherwise $p\implies q$ would be false.  Analogue, if $p$ is false using the other implication.

Comment: [Here's a tableaux generator.](https://www.umsu.de/trees/)

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I have not studied formal logic so I am not sure if this is correct but here is my thought on this. $q\to p$ OR $q\to\neg p$  
**Case 1:**  
Say, $q\to\neg p\to\neg q\implies q\to\neg q$. Hence, a contradiction.

**Case 2:**  
$q\to p\to q\implies q\to q$ A tautology. 

Hence, $q\equiv p$

Comment: @Peter That is the correct concept, but how do you write that in a proof with logic symbols (i.e. how do you write "analogue" and "otherwise" in symbolic notation)?

Comment: By formal proof, do you mean natural deduction

Comment: @Manx Yes, natural deduction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

To prove this use natural deduction, in general we will use $\leftrightarrow\text{ Intro }$, so we want to first assume $Q$, see if this indeed implies $P$, another direction is trivial by $\to\text{ Elim }$ from $P\to Q$.

**Answer:**

$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{1.~P\to Q\\2.~\neg P\to \neg Q}{\fitch{3.~Q}{\fitch{4.~\neg P}{5.~\neg Q\hspace{10ex}\to\text{ Elim }2,4\\6.~\bot\hspace{12.5ex}\bot\text{ Intro }3,5}\\7.~\neg\neg P\hspace{13.2ex}\neg\text{ Intro }4-6\\8.~P\hspace{16.2ex}\neg\neg\text{ Elim }7}\\\fitch{9.~P}{10.~Q\hspace{14.5ex}\to\text{ Elim }1,9}\\11.~P\leftrightarrow Q\hspace{12.5ex}\leftrightarrow\text{ Intro }3-8,9-10}$$

---

> $\underline{\text{Definition}}$
>   Formulas $P$ and $Q$ are **logically equivalent** if and only if the statement of their **material equivalence** $(P\leftrightarrow Q)$ is a tautology.
>   (There is a difference between being true and being a tautology)

If we have premise says $P\to Q$ and $\neg P\to\neg Q$ are tautology this is reasonable:

$$\begin{align}
1.~&P\to Q\equiv \top&&\text{Premise}\\
2.~&\neg P\to \neg Q\equiv \top&&\text{Premise}\\
3.~&Q\to P\equiv \top&&\text{Contrapositive 2}\\
4.~&P\to Q\land Q\to P\equiv\top\land\top\equiv \top&&\text{Domination law 1,3}\\
5.~&P\leftrightarrow Q\equiv\top&&\text{Biconditional equivalence 4}\\
6.~&P\equiv Q&&\text{Definition 5}
\end{align}$$

However if the premise only says $P\to Q$ and $\neg P\to\neg Q$ are true, we only know that $P\leftrightarrow Q$ is also true, which might not be a tautology.

Comment: Getting to that step is fairly straightforward. Now that you have established that p↔q is a tautology, what theorem/law/definition proves that p must be logically equivalent to q?

Comment: This proof didn't show $p\leftrightarrow q$ is a tautology, what had been proved is with premises $p\to q$ and $\neg p\to\neg q$, $p\leftrightarrow q$ must also been true, however by $p\leftrightarrow q$ itself it's not a tautology, which means $p$ and $q$ are not logically equivalent, see [The difference between “logical equivalence” and “material equivalence”](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/65024/what-is-the-difference-between-logical-equivalence-and-material-equivalence)

Comment: Sorry, I meant in this particular case. I know p↔q is not a tautology alone. The objective of this proof is to show that p and q are logically equivalent in this particular case. No generalities implied.

Answer (score 1):

$p$ and $q$ are of course *not* logically equivalent. However, you *can* derive the truth of $p \leftrightarrow q$ from those two premises ... which is probably what you are really asked to do.

Comment: The premises are known to be true. Therefore p↔q is a tautology.

Comment: @Thicc No. Therefore $p \leftrightarrow q$ is true. That's not the same as being a tautology.

Comment: It is a tautology in this particular case because the premises are known to be true. p↔q is not a tautology in general.

Comment: @Thicc I don't know what textbook you are using, but I have never heard of a tautology-under-certain-assumptions. The tautology I know is a statement that is *always* true, no exceptions.